# Xunit Timeout parameter: minimal working example

Tags: c#, timeout, xunit.net

I'm trying to create a minimal working example of how the `Timeout` parameter in Xunit.net operates. I currently have the following `Fact` example, but it isn't operating as I expect, as it fails the test:

```cs
[Fact(Timeout = 50)]
public void FactTimeout_TimeoutLessThanProcessingTime_ThrowTestTimeoutException()
{
    // Arrange
    // Act
    Action act = () => Task.Delay(5000);

    // Assert
    Assert.Throws<TestTimeoutException>(act);
}
```

Is this correct, or is my understand wrong? Is there something else that needs to be changed or added to the test itself, or the Xunit config?

#### Update

Based on @RubenBartelink's answer I got the following to work:

```
// Will generate the exception and display it in the results window
[Fact(Timeout = 50)]
public async void TestOne() => await Task.Delay(5000);

// This will pass the test, but will complain that it is not awaited
[Fact(Timeout = 50)]
public void TestTwo() => Assert.ThrowsAsync<TestTimeoutException>(() => Task.Delay(5000));
```

Comment: you need to `await` the `ThrowsAsync` - otherwise tou've just produced a `Task` that nobody will ever inspect the result of. The problem though is that `TestTimeoutException` is an internal exception that's thrown by xUnit when a test times out - there is no real other way to make it be thrown within the body of your test (which for me begs the question of what you're looking to achieve overall - what will you do if it times out in your real code?)

Comment: @RubenBartelink Ah, I should have been clearer up-front. I'm creating an example project to demonstrate how to different aspects of Xunit are used. So, you're right about that approach not being suitable for actual testing. Can the `Timeout` parameter be used in a **non**-async situation, say you have a synchronous piece of code that just takes ages?

Comment: Yes, that timeout applies regardless of Sync or Async. In general, for a test suite as a whole, I'd be looking at having a timeout for the test suite as a whole (in general any runner will have such a facility, as xunit.runner.console has for instacne) and then let the CI rig's timing guide you to anything that's taking too long in general. i.e. while the Timeout facility can be indepensible when needed, I'd tend not to mention it in any high level overview

Comment: So it turns out that the `Timeout` parameter doesn't currently work on synchronous code, I ended up asked on the xunit.slack channel as I couldn't get a sync example going.

Comment: ah, interesting. :thinking: is there some way you could abuse it by doing `async Task Test () => {.... (take >50ms); await Task.FromResult(0); }` - let's pretend that thought didnt enter my head!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You likely mean to use `Assert.ThrowsAsync` - otherwise you're measuring how long it takes to *kick off* the task (assuming the 50 means you intend to set a timeout of 50ms and you just want to prove it can indeed fail)

While there are cases where you can avoid it, in general, I make such an async Test Method be `async Task ...` and ensure there is an `await` in there to make it easier to follow the flow (assuming `Async`ness is key to your test)

You may find discussion/examples in https://github.com/xunit/xunit/issues/217 useful

---

EDIT: Example untested impl per your comment

I'm trying to create a minimal working example of how the Timeout parameter in Xunit.net operates. I currently have the following Fact example, but it isn't operating as I expect, as it fails the test:

```
[Fact(Timeout = 50)]
public async Task FactTimeout_TimeoutLessThanProcessingTime_ThrowTestTimeoutException()
{
    Action act = () => Task.Delay(5000);

    // Trigger the timeout by attempting something that will take too long
    await act;
}
```

this should internally result in a test timeout (the `TestTimeoutException` you were trying to catch). I suspect there won't be a neat way for you to catch the exception in question - if you need to observe and react to the timeout occurring and do something explicit (which you ideally want to avoid doing in a test), you'll need to explicitly manage that by doing a `Task.WhenAny` roughly like this:

```
public async Task FactTimeout_TimeoutLessThanProcessingTime_ThrowTestTimeoutException()
{
    Action act = () => Task.Delay(5000);

    let timeoutTask = Task.Delay(50);
    let res = await Task.WhenAny(timeoutTask, act);

    Assert.IsSame(timeoutTask, res);
}
```

NB this is only as an example to show that the timeout does happen and can be observed - the former approach with correct `awaiting` and letting xUnit manage the timeout without polluting the test with this sort of logic is where you want to arrive at.

Comment: Could you provide a minimum example of the test throwing a `TestTimeoutException`? Previously I tried `Thread.Sleep`, but that produced the same result.

Comment: Dont have an env ready but will add an example inline which you can try

Comment: I've added an update to my question with findings based on your answer. I found a way to pass that test, but couldn't find a way of doing that and getting rid of the message that the call isn't awaited. Any changes you can think of to achieve both?